# React: On which lifecycle hook should I parse new received data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to parse data received from firebase and pass this new data to a component. The data is fetched asyncronously with promises. The problem that I encounter is that it's not rendered the first time, even though I have set up `componentDidMount` and called the function to parse the data there.

The data I recieve from firebase is as follows:

```
faults: [{
  name: "Foo",
  status: "Open"
  type: "type1"
},
{
  name: "Bar",
  status: "Open"
  type: "type2"
}],
types: [{
  key: "type1",
  type: "Accident"
},
{
  key: "type2",
  type: "Crash"
}]
```

As you can see I need to parse the data to replace the `type` of faults with the correct name from `types`.

For doing so I have a function that parses the data and sets a state. This is the code for that:

```
parseFields() {
    let parsedFields = [];
    this.props.fields.forEach((field) => {
      const typeSelected= this.props.estados.find(element => element.key === field.type) || '';

      let parsedField = Object.assign({}, field);

      parsedField['type'] = typeSelected.type;

      parsedFields.push(parsedField);
    });
    this.setState({data: parsedFields});
  }
```

This function is called on `componentDidMount` and on `componentWillReceiveProps`, but when the component mounts no data is shown. However when the component receives new props it is shown correctly.

Am I doing something wrong? I have tried calling this function on `componentWillMount` too but it doesn't work for the first render.

## Update

As requested this is the component code:

```
import React from 'react'

import Table from './Table';

class FaultList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.columns = [
      {
        name: 'Name',
        field: 'name'
      },
      {
        name: 'Type',
        field: 'type'
      },
      {
        name: 'Status',
        field: 'status'
      }
    ];

    this.state = {
      faults: []
    };

    this.parseFields = this.parseFields.bind(this);
  }

  parseFields() {
    let parsedFields = [];
    this.props.fields.forEach((field) => {
      const typeSelected= this.props.types.find(element => element.key === field.type) || '';

      let parsedField = Object.assign({}, field);

      parsedField['type'] = typeSelected.type;

      parsedFields.push(parsedField);
    });
    this.setState({data: parsedFields});
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.parseFields();
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps() {
    this.parseFields();
   }

  render() {
    return(
      <Table
        data={this.state.faults}
        columns={this.columns}
        handleClick={this.props.handleClick}
        />
    );
  }
}

export default FaultList;
```

This is the code responsible for handling the data fetching which is handled in the parent component:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.faultsRef= ref.child('faults');

    this.faultsRef.on('value', (snap) => {
      let faults= [];
      snap.forEach((child) => {
        let fault= child.val();
        let key = child.key;
        const finalFault = update(fault, {$merge: {key}});
        faults.push(finalFault);
      });
      this.setState({faults});
    });

    get('types')
    .then((types) => {
      this.setState({types});
    });
  }
```

The code for the get function is:

```
function get(node) {
  return ref.child(node).once('value')
  .then((snap) => {
    let list = [];

    snap.forEach((child) => {
      let object = child.val();
      let key = child.key;
      const finalObject = update(object , {$merge: {key}});
      list .push(finalObject);
    });

    return list;
  });
}
```

## Update 2:

I've noticed something very very strange. If I reorder a bit of code in the ´componentDidMount´ of the parent component and I first retrieve the list of types and then get the list of faults, the first re-render is done correctly but the types aren't parsed so I'm left with empty cells in my table.

Comment: Can you post your component code? Specifically, you should be using `this.state.data` somewhere.

Comment: I've updated the question. Sorry for the delay, as I have to translate the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your component correctly, `FaultList` doesn't do anything asynchronously and simply receives props from the parent. Given that, you can simplify things by making `FaultList` stateless and just parsing the data in `render` directly. The component will-re-render (ie: `render` will be called) whenever the component receives new props, and the data will be re-parsed.

```
class FaultList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.columns = [
      ...
    ];

    this.parseFields = this.parseFields.bind(this);
  }

  // You no longer need `componentDidMount` and `componentWillReceiveProps`

  parseFields() {
    let parsedFields = [];
    this.props.fields.forEach((field) => {
      const typeSelected= this.props.types.find(element => element.key === field.type) || '';

      let parsedField = Object.assign({}, field);
      parsedField['type'] = typeSelected.type;
      parsedFields.push(parsedField);
    });

    // Note: we are now returning the value instead of setting `state`.
    return parsedFields;
  }

  render() {        
    return(
      <Table
        data={this.parseFields()}
        columns={this.columns}
        handleClick={this.props.handleClick}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default FaultList;
```

Comment: Yes! That was what I was looking for! I've found another work around but I like your answer much more! Thanks a lot! :D

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `this.state.data` on your `Table` component instead of `this.state.faults`:

```
  <Table
    data={this.state.data}
    columns={this.columns}
    handleClick={this.props.handleClick}
    />
```

Comment: Yes, that solves the first re-render but I need to parse the data before it's rendered. Perhaps I'm not doing the parsing in the correct lifecycle. Also maybe I could overwrite the state with the parsed data but I don't think that is the correct solution.

Comment: So after re-render everything is fine? the problem is only on initial render? Isn't it beacue your `types` data is fetched asynchronously so `types` hasn't been fetched yet when the component is rendered for the first time?

Comment: Yes, that was part of the problem. The key was to parse the fields on FaultList via the props recieved from the parent component. See the accepted answer for more info. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found what the problem was. As [Bartek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7518718/bartek-fryzowicz) mentioned that Table component should have a reference to the status so all I have to do was to move parseFields to the parent component and call it everytime firebase retrieves new data. This is the code for that:

```
class FaultsView extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.faultsRef = null;

    this.state = {
      faults: [],
      parsedFaults: [],
      types: []
    };

    this.parseFields = this.parseFields.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    get('types')
    .then((types) => {
      this.setState({types});
    });

    this.faultsRef = ref.child('faults');

    this.faultsRef.on('value', (snap) => {
      let faults= [];
      snap.forEach((child) => {
        let fault= child.val();
        let key = child.key;
        const finalFault = update(fault, {$merge: {key}});
        faults.push(finalFault);
      });
      this.setState({faults});
      // This was the fix!
      this.parseFields();
    });
  }

  componentWillUnMount() {
    this.faultsRef.off();
  }

  parseFields() {
    let parsedFields = [];
    this.props.fields.forEach((field) => {
      const typeSelected= this.props.types.find(element => element.key === field.type) || '';

      let parsedField = Object.assign({}, field);

      parsedField['type'] = typeSelected.type;

      parsedFields.push(parsedField);
    });
    this.setState({data: parsedFields});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <FaultList
          faults={this.state.parsedFaults}
          handleClick={this.handleClick}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default FaultsView;
```